# Samsung phones and Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT bug?

Tags: android

I developed a timer application but some people noticed that the notification never stops on their Samsung Galaxy or Spica.

I have these flags attached to my notification :

`notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;`

I'm not really sure this is the issue but I can't think of any other thing to cause this (and I don't have any samsung phone to test it)...

Do you have any idea why would it bug especially on Samsung phones ?
How could I make the notification sound to loop without using this `Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;` ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a Samsung phone in the lab in my Secret Mountain Lair, so I don't know if this is a bug or not.

You can always cancel the `Notification` yourself via whatever you're launching with the `contentIntent` and/or `deleteIntent` `PendingIntent` values.