# Sound played with FLAG_INSISTENT notifications don't stop when my app cancels the notification

Tags: android, notifications

I have an application that has a reminder feature. When it's time to remind the user of something, my application creates a notification, possibly using FLAG_INSISTENT to ensure the alarm is heard. Once the user interacts with my app to acknowledge the alarm, the app cancels the notification.

The user can launch the app either by pulling down the notification bar and tapping on my notification -- in which case everything is fine -- or by navigating to the app some other way, such as by launching it from the home screen. If the user uses the notification bar method, the FLAG_INSISTENT audio stops when the user touches the notification bar. But here's the problem: if the user enters the app directly without touching the notification bar. the audio for the FLAG_INSISTENT alarm keeps playing indefinitely -- even after my app cancels the notification. The only way a user can stop it is to pull down the notification bar (or reboot the device!).

I've been getting tons of bug reports from angry users ever since the optional FLAG_INSISTENT feature went live. It doesn't seem specific to one platform; users reporting this bug have hardware including a Motorol Razr Maxx HD, Samsung Galaxy Note, and HTC EVO 4G LTE. I've had frustrated users report that they resorted to uninstalling the app to stop the noise, and even then said it wouldn't stop. Searching the web has been fruitless.

The notifications are being created in more-or-less the garden variety way:

```
notification = new Notification(
                R.drawable.icon,
                message,
                System.currentTimeMillis()
                );

if (userDefinedaCustomSound) {
   notification.sound = Uri.parse(userSelectedReminderSound);
} else {
   notification.defaults |= DEFAULT_SOUND;
}

notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
notification.ledOnMS = 300;
notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
notification.flags |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;

if (userWantsContinuousAlarm) {
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
}

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_BAR_ID, notification);
```

And are being cancelled thusly:

```
nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_BAR_ID);
```

I've tried adding the FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL to the notification; that has no effect. As a workaround, I've also tried modifying my cancel method so that it first issues a new notification with no sound, and without FLAG_INSISTENT, then cancels; again, the audio just keeps on playing.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's no way to mute the sound, but the solutions are, keep your audio short, not repeatable and if possible just cancel the entire Notification, then post it again without the sound.

Comment: As I mentioned in the last part of my post, I already tried cancelling the entire notification and then reposting it without the sound. The sound still continued.

The length of the audio doesn't matter because by definition of the problem (since I'm posting it with FLAG_INSISTENT), it will keep repeating the audio no matter what it is.

Comment: I'm sure this link will solve your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261539/samsung-phones-and-notification-flag-insistent-bug

Comment: That post just suggests cancelling the notification -- which I am already doing. The problem is that the sound keeps playing even after the notification has been cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. The audio keep on playing after the notification was cancelled.

I formulated this work around,

1. Perform a normal notification cancelled.`mNotificationManager.cancel(getNotificationID(event));`
2. Immediately Create another notification with sound. **Use the default Alarm**.
3. Immediately cancel the notification.

Note:

- The sound played as part of the notification was not the default.
- method getNotificationID(event) always return the same constant for the same event object type.
- Notification with sound played using the default will stop when the notification is cancelled.
- I set the sound using builder using this
  `setSound(Uri.parse(this.sharedPreferences.getString(key,"")))`

From the observations, I think it might be a bug. The reference to the ringtone object was not properly retained so when the cancel was called, it failed to call on the ringtone `.stop()` or was unable to do so.

Hope you can used it too.

---

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.cancel(getNotificationID(event));
audioAlarmTriggered.remove(event.sensortype);

NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
builder.setAutoCancel(true)
       .setSound(ringtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));
mNotificationManager.notify(getNotificationID(event), builder.build());
mNotificationManager.cancel(getNotificationID(event));
```

Answer (score 0):

If above code is in your service class. Then I think the problem is when you open app directly instead using notification bar, that time its not calling your service class else you need to call nm.cancel(NOTIFICATION_BAR_ID); from the activity which opens while clicking on notification.

And to do so you need a global class which keeps static NOTIFICATION_BAR_ID, so that will be helpful to you for managing cancel method.

I hope, this will solve your problem.

Comment: NOTIFICATION_BAR_ID is a constant. The app is already cancelling the notification, and the cancel works in every other aspect (e.g., the icon disappears from the notification bar).

Comment: I think your problem is device specific. Test your app on multiple devices

Comment: As I mentioned in my original post, "It doesn't seem specific to one platform; users reporting this bug have hardware including a Motorol Razr Maxx HD, Samsung Galaxy Note, and HTC EVO 4G LTE."